# Display a right-click menu using a shell script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, x11, menu

Is it possible to display a right-click menu using a shell script (or some kind of Unix command?) I'm trying to find a program that can be used to display a context menu at a specific location on the screen.

For example, it would be useful to display the desktop right-click context menu programmatically (the one that appears when right-clicking on a file.) This would require some method of launching the desktop right-click menu from the command line.

Comment: This might be relevant (a Java popup window that closes automatically when the user clicks outside it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675912/how-to-close-a-modal-jdialog-when-user-clicks-outside-of-jdialog It might be possible to modify this program so that it can be launched at a specific screen position using a shell script.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml), see the `MOUSE COMMANDS` section of the manual, specifically the `click` argument.

Comment: Do you mean this section here? http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#mouse_commands

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Yes.

Comment: Do the mouse commands do anything besides moving the mouse to a specific position on the screen? (Specifically, which commands can be used to display a context menu at a specific position on the screen?)

Comment: @AndersonGreen It's not that simple. You need to find and activate the window (see the window section of that manual), then right click on that window using the `click` command.